# Custom zoom percentage in Windows 7 Paint

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-paint

I’m looking for a way to set a custom zoom in MS Paint. The default zoom levels in Paint are 50%, 100%, 200%, etc. and sometimes the jump between percentages is too great for what I’m doing. I’m aware I can use the magnifier tool to sort-of set a zoom level, but it's a bit cumbersome and not all that flexible. I’m curious if there is another solution.

Comment: Resizing (scaling) doesn't work either, since it's a lossey operation (try resizing to 10%, then 500%).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you can't. Surprisingly, that feature has never existed (neither in the old Win XP).

If it's something you really need, the only thing I can do is suggest you to use [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/), which is free and way more powerful than Paint.

Comment: Agh, that's unfortunate. I already have Gimp installed, but still prefer Paint for quick editing tasks since it doesn't take 15 seconds to fire up. Guess it's something I'll have to continue to put up with.

Comment: I second this notion... GIMP is excellent for GUI mocks.

Comment: @jjjjjjjjjjj I was going to reply how I've never had GIMP start up anywhere near that quick for me... but then I timed it and it come out at exactly 30 seconds.